# Upgrade to Spring Boot 2.4 break Spock Spring mocks

Tags: java, spring-boot, groovy, spock

I'm upgrading a Spring Boot application from 2.3.10.RELEASE to 2.4.12. The tests have been written with Spock 2.0-groovy-3.0.

When I run the following example integration test in Spring Boot 2.4 (that worked in 2.3)

```
@SpringBootTest
class DummyIntegrationSpec extends Specification {

  @SpringBean
  CollectivePartnerLookupService collectivePartnerLookupService = Mock()

  void "hello"() {
    expect:
    true
  }
}
```

I get the following error.

```
Failed to load ApplicationContext
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:248)
    at org.spockframework.spring.SpringTestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(SpringTestContextManager.java:56)
    at org.spockframework.spring.SpringInterceptor.interceptInitializerMethod(SpringInterceptor.java:46)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.AbstractMethodInterceptor.intercept(AbstractMethodInterceptor.java:24)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:101)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$1(NodeTestTask.java:111)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:111)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:79)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.model.MethodInfo.invoke(MethodInfo.java:148)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$3.run(TestWorker.java:193)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:133)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:71)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot register alias 'collectivePartnerLookupService' for name 'a.b.c.CollectivePartnerLookupService#0': Alias would override bean definition 'collectivePartnerLookupService'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.checkForAliasCircle(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1131)
    at org.springframework.core.SimpleAliasRegistry.registerAlias(SimpleAliasRegistry.java:79)
    at org.spockframework.spring.mock.SpockMockPostprocessor.registerAliases(SpockMockPostprocessor.java:116)
    at org.spockframework.spring.mock.SpockMockPostprocessor.registerMock(SpockMockPostprocessor.java:110)
    at org.spockframework.spring.mock.SpockMockPostprocessor.register(SpockMockPostprocessor.java:92)
    at org.spockframework.spring.mock.SpockMockPostprocessor.postProcessBeanFactory(SpockMockPostprocessor.java:85)
    at org.spockframework.spring.mock.SpockMockPostprocessor.postProcessBeanFactory(SpockMockPostprocessor.java:78)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:325)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:191)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:771)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:763)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:438)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:123)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    ... 59 more
```

Does anyone know what might be the problem and how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research I have stumbled over the following setting that needs to be applied to the `application-test.properties` or `application-test.yml` file.

```
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

It seems that Spring has changed the default value from `true` to `false` and in order to keep allowing Spock to replace Spring beans this has to be manually set to `true` again.